# Round Number to first decimal place

Tags: actionscript-3

I'd like to round down to half of the first decimal place.

So if I had 1.45 it would round to 1. If I had 1.55 it would round down to 1.5. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Math.floor(x*2)/2`

This should do.